# "Gang of Four" Design Patterns in Magento Core

Tags: programming, core

There are a few very obvious patterns in use in Magento's core, such as:

- Singleton
- Registry
- Event/Observer
- Factory
- Model/View/Controller

But there are others that may be in use in Magento that I'm not aware of such as Actor, Decorator, Strategy patterns.

Is there a reference list of the usage of all pattern types in Magento or how to implement in third party modules that don't unnecessarily replicate built-in functionality of Magento?

Comment: Short answer: no. But you forgot MVC :-)

Comment: Actually there is a list of design patterns on Stack Overflow (have the link in my bookmarks:)) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041473/magento-design-patterns

Comment: Upvote just because of that link back to SO.

Comment: Wow. That was *exactly* what I was looking for. Please post as an answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[There is a list of design patterns which are used in Magento on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041473/magento-design-patterns)

From the article:

> The obvious ones are:
>
> **Factory:**
>
> ```
> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
> ```
>
> **Singleton:**
>
> ```
> $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session');
> ```
>
> **Registry:**
>
> ```
> $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
> ```
>
> **View Helper:**
>
> ```
> Mage::helper('core');
> ```
>
> **Prototype:**
>
> ```
> Mage:getModel('catalog/product')->getTypeInstance();
> ```
>
> **Object Pool:**
>
> ```
> $id = Mage::objects()->save($object);
> $object = Mage::objects($id);
> ```
>
> **Iterator:**
>
> ```
> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
> ```
>
> **Event/Listeners:**
>
> ```
> Mage::dispatchEvent('model_load_before', $params);
> ```

**EDIT**

> **Active record**
>
> ```
> $product->save()
> $product->getName()
> ```
>
> **Null object**
>
> ```
> $collection->getFirstItem()
> ```
>
> **Lazy loading** - collections are loaded when iterated

There are also [5 articles on Ryan Street blog](http://www.coolryan.com/?s=Magento%20Design%20Patterns) about MVC, Front Controller, Factory, Singleton and Registry in Magento

**Edit**
I might add that the Magento 'singleton' is more a pseudo-singleton. It's a combination of 'Factory' because Mage::getSingleton() is a factory and 'Registry' because inside the `getSingleton()` method this is called

```
self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments))
```

Comment: I might add 'Active record' (`$product->save()`, `$product->getName()`, ...), 'Null object' (`$collection->getFirstItem()`),  'Front controller', `Lazy loading' (collections are loaded when iterated)

Comment: @Marius feel free to edit the answer.