# Best Way To Iterate Through Product Collection

Tags: best-practice, catalog-optimize

Which of these methods is "*easier*" on the Magento platform, specifically the database? Method 1 uses a single call to the database to retrieve the collection, and then iterates over the result. Method 2 retrieves the product inside the loop on each run.

### Method 1

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // <- obv a bad idea
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'sku', array('in' => $productSkus)
    )
    ->load();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getName();
}
```

Versus getting the product object inside the loop:

### Method 2

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

foreach ($array as $key => value) {
    $product = $products->load('PROD001', 'sku');
}
```

Obviously this code is only a sample. Considering the dataset could contain many hundreds or thousands of products, which method is the "*right*" way, or is there another I'm missing?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/gang-of-four-design-patterns-in-magento-core also check out: http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2014/02/20/magento-design-patterns-part-8-iterator/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Method 1 is going to take a lot less time to loop through, but will consume a lot of memory.

Another option which is probably the one you are looking for is using the:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')
```

This describes it sort of: [Is it possible to iterate over Magento collections with pagination natively?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-magento-collections-with-pagination-natively)

Make sure to pay attention to Batched Iterator by Kalen Jordan
https://gist.github.com/kalenjordan/5483065

This can be used to accomplish very large datasets elegantly.

Comment: Thanks Aepod, using Method 1, with `getResourceSingleton()` instead of `getResourceModel()` seems to offer the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Jongosi No that brings nothing good from method 2 and only adds problems instead. The collection resource model has lots of state, you don't want to instantiate it as singleton.