# Magento programmatically force all products to save

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, products, magento-community

I have a magento installation that has a layered navigation to which attributes show and allow you to filter by.

I have an issue with the attributes showing on the filter, they wont show unless I go into each product and re-save them after I have imported the attribute data via CSV.

I have re-indexed the data and flushed all cache but still cant get them to show.

I need to find a way to force all products to re-save programatically.

Does anyone know of a script I can run via SSH to do this at all?  I have tried a few I have found online, but they dont seem to execute correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried reindex from console/terminal? $~ php shell/indexer.php -reindexall is command for that on unix systems with ability to run php scripts from terminal

Answer (score 1):

Untested but something like this:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';


Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo 'saving product '.$product->getData('sku').PHP_EOL;
    $product->save();
    echo 'saved'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: how many products do you have?

Comment: 750 products.  I have just managed to sort this though.  I have updated products via the Admin panel.  Batch updated attributes, changed all to Taxable Goods and updated.  Now working, thanks for your help though, Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

This is what resource iterators are made for:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($productCollection->getSelect(), array(array($this, 'productCallback')));

// callback method
public function productCallback($args)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'your_changed_attribute1');
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'your_changed_attribute2');
}
```

Note: Since you might only have an issue with some of your attributes, there's no need to do call the 'full' `->save()` functions on your products and this is a quite heavy operation. Just select the attributes which you need to save as shown above.

Credits & links for you to look at:

[Best Way To Iterate Through Product Collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16540/best-way-to-iterate-through-product-collection)

[Is it possible to iterate over Magento collections with pagination natively?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-magento-collections-with-pagination-natively)

Comment: I like this&ndash;it gives you the ORM for building your query and then a very high-speed way to process and update the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setPageSize(100);
for ($i = 0; $i < $products->getLastPageNumber(); $i++) {
    $products
        ->setCurPage($i)
        ->save();
}
```