# Products not showing on site after reindex!

Tags: product, reindex

I just ran manual reindexing of some indexes on my magento site, from /ROOT/shell/ using

```
php indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_flat

php indexer.php -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

php indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

Now most of my products are missing from the site! For example I'll go to a category, it will show a count of 14 items but only 4 are listed. My layered nav also will show proper counts, for example 5 items between $0-$250, but when I filter by it I only see 1 item, even though the count at the top shows 5 results.

If I go to the backend, go into an item, and then save it, it will then show up again on the site. But with 7000+ products I can't feasibly re-save each one manually. I am on a time crunch here to get this fixed asap. Any ideas?

Comment: Try the answer [suggested here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56286/magento-programmatically-force-all-products-to-save)?

Comment: What version of Magento? Any caching mechanisms? Any errors when running `php -f cron.php` or `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall` ?